# How to update the state value using setTimeout in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Am trying to reset the state value after some time using setTimeout function.

```
const SetTimeout = props => {
  let [errorText, setError] = useState(
    props.errorMessage ? props.errorMessage : ""
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorText !== "") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setError("");
      }, 4000);
    } else {
      // console.log("no error")
    }
  }, [errorText]);
  return <div>{errorText}</div>;
};

const MapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.errorReducer.error
  };
};
```

Am getting the `errorMessage` from an api call, after some time i'm trying to make that message to empty using useState.

But the component is getting re-rendered with the same error message. could you please help me in fixing this?

Comment: Your code works for me. The only thing I can thing of is that Redux is re-rendering causing the error to be pushed into the component again. Are you clearing the error in Redux also?

Comment: No am just taking the error message from redux

Comment: so you want to show your error message for some time and then hide it?

Comment: You will need to remove the error from Redux. Otherwise, any re-renders will push the message back into the component. Other answers say you should be using redux for this but only you know where this state belongs. But you cant mix them.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing component state and redux state here which is pretty bad and why you are seeing this behaviour.

You are initially rendering the component with the error message from within Redux, and passing this into the component as a property value. The component displays this, set's it's own state value. After the timeout runs, it's updating it's own state, which causes a re-render, and the Redux value is again passed into the component via the properties.

I would suggest you forget about using `useState` and use a Redux action to clear the error message that it is storing.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `redux` to not use state in react components and here you are using state in your component. so what you can do is to add the `erromessage` to your global state :

```
state ={
...,
errormessage:undefined
}
```

and then in your action you need to change your `state.errormessage` like this:

```
export const show_error = message => {
    return {
        type: "SHOW_ERROR",
        payload: message
    };
};
export const remove_error = () => {
    return {
        type:"REMOVE_ERROR"
    };
};
```

imagine calling `post api` to add post using `redux thunk` you  can do it like this:

```
export function add_post(data) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return axios
            .post('/posts', data)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(fetch_posts_data());})
            .catch(err =>  dispatch(
                    show_error(err)
                );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    dispatch(remove_error());
                }, 2000););
    };
}
```

in your reducer :

```
 case "SHOW_ERROR":
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: { ...state.posts, errormessage: action.message}
            };
        case "REMOVE_ERROR":
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: { ...state.posts, errormessage: undefined }
            };
```

now to retrieve the `errormessage` in your component you can use normal `connect` method but here i will use redux hooks `useSelector()`:

```
const Error = ()=>{
 const errormessage = useSelector(state=>state.errormessage)
     return(
    <>
     {

    errormessage?
    <div>{errormessage}</div>
    :""

    }
    </>
       )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this out! So it may not be perfect.

Hooks have a `useSelector` and a `useDispatch` (from `react-redux`)

To stick with having your error in Redux, you component would look like this:

```
const SetTimeout = () => {
    const errorText = useSelector(state => state.errorReducer.error);
    const clearError = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (errorText !== "") {
            const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                clearError({ type: "CLEAR_ERROR" });
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            // console.log("no error")
        }
        // this will clear Timeout when component unmounts like in willComponentUnmount
        return () => { clearTimeout(timeout); };
    }, []);

    return <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorText}</div>;
};

export default SetTimeout;
```

Pretty cool functional component without the redux boiler plate code.

Hope that helps